# じ/ず conversion in 人は動かじ

Tags: auxiliaries, auxiliary-ず

There is this famous quote reputedly from 山本五十六:

> やってみせて、言って聞かせて、やらせてみて、 ほめてやらねば人は動かじ。([source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/quote/154/))
> やってみせ、言ってきかせて、させてみて、誉めてやらねば人は動かじ。(a different version. [source](https://www.komcon.co.jp/ml/1166/))
> Do it and show'em; say things and make'em listen; try and let'em do things; and if you don't praise people (for what they do), people don't lift a finger. (My rendering)

It appears 動かじ = 動かず, but I can't find anything on [Wikipedia's 四つ仮名 page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D) about this conversion. Is this a marker of [Early Modern Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_Japanese) or a dialect?

Comment: [じ](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/じ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[じ(まじ)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%81%98%20%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98) is an auxiliary verb that means *will not* (as opposed to ず meaning *not*). So 動かじ means *(People) will not move/take actions*.